# Rich Decorators for types in scala are part of Scala.runtime. Why?

Tags: scala

I want to understand why Rich Decorators over basic types say Int which has RichInt as type which adds a lot of utility methods ( I guess ) are part of scala.runtime and not say probably scala.util...? Are there any reasons for the same or just they are there because they are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess it's because they're important enough to need to be imported automatically, so there's no need to expose them in a package like `scala.util` that contains optional imports that you need to do manually. `runtime` isn't a package that users are really supposed to need to look at.

Comment: There are actually not imported automatically. Only `java.lang`, `scala` and `scala.Predef` are. They are usually brought into play by implicit conversion through `LowPriorityImplicits` which in inherited by `Predef`. So technically the Rich* classes could be defined in `scala.util`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that technically it's automatic conversions to them that are imported. The point remains: the user doesn't need to import them manually as generally they're not something you should need to touch.